# Как может одна переменная сессии сохраняться, а вторая теряться при воследующих запросах?

Tags: php, сессия

В начале скрипта проверяю сессию: `if (session_id() == ''){session_start();}`

Через POST-запрос один раз приходят данные авторизации, при успешной проверке которых устанавливаются переменные:

```
$_SESSION['User'] = $Account['username'];
$_SESSION['Permissions'] = $Account['permissions'];
```

... и всё - больше они нигде не перезаписываются, только читаются методами `isset($_SESSION['User'], $_SESSION['Permissions'])` и `json_decode($_SESSION['Permissions'])`

Скрипт на странице периодически отправляет GET-ы для обновления данных, и после оного такого GET-а, в котором проверяется `isset` этих переменных, `$_SESSION['Permissions']` по непонятным мне причинам становится `null`, о чём говорят дампы этой переменной и ответы сервера типа

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in ... />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in ...
```

При этом `$_SESSION['User']` остаётся на месте.

Версия php 5.3, apache 2.2 (по техническим ограничениям обновлять нельзя)

При этом, на localhost-е с аналогичными версиями php и сервера таких проблем НЕТ!

**Что может влиять на "потерю" переменной сессии?**

Answer (score 4):

Код, который удаляет из сессии эту переменную. Или не удаляет.

Учитывая, что isset у вас возвращает "null", а в json_decode() передается **массив**, то дело тут совсем не в сессиях. Как говорится, дело было не в бобине.

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION['Permissions']);` перед проверкой `isset($_SESSION['User'], $_SESSION['Permissions'])`, показывает `NULL` - как вообще эта проверка возвращает true??

Comment: для null isset вернет false. проверяй себя снова

Comment: Один и тот же код без ошибок работает на localhost, и работает через одно место на реальном сервере. Уточню вопрос: какие параметры конфигурации сервера или php могут влиять на такое поведение переменных сессии?

Comment: никакие, разумеется.

Comment: ОК... После инициализации `$_SESSION['Permissions']` при авторизации, gettype на этой переменной показывает string, при GET-запросе от уже авторизованного пользователя gettype показывает array, а var_dump - NULL. Переменная нигде не инициализируется повторно, только читается... В чём подвох?

Comment: подвох в том, что надо. обязательно. верить. своим. глазам. Если gettype показывает array, это значит, что где-то в коде строка перезаписывается на массив. В барабашек люди обычно перестают верить года к пяти. Я ОЧЕНЬ надеюсь, что ты уже вышел из этого возраста.